# Android FCM define channel ID and send notification to this channel through PHP

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I'm totally lost on this, got like 20 tabs open to solve this annoying puzzle. I've gone though multiple tutorials but none of them answer where to define a channel ID and how to send a notification through PHP to it.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage!!.data["message"]!!)
}

private fun showNotification(message: String) {

    val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, com.amoflirt.amoflirt.R.drawable.ic_vip_heart))
            .setSmallIcon(com.amoflirt.amoflirt.R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)


    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    manager.notify(0, builder.build())
}
```

No matter what I change here, it doesn't effect the way the notifications are sent/received, like setLargeIcon isn't adding anything.

This is the PHP:

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxx');

 $msg = array(
            'body'  => $body,
            'title' => $title,
            );

$fields = array(
                'to' => $token,
                'notification'  => $msg
                );


$headers = array
            (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
echo $result;
curl_close( $ch );
```

I tried all kind of  "solutions" to add a large icon and vibration on both sides (android and PHP) but none of them works. But the most important is I don't understand how to add the damn channels and how to send the notifications to them. Why do android as a whole have to be such a mess and pile of dog crap :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should just read the official documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support . I updated @Nasdomlan 's anwer below. I tested it and it works. You can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I updated @Nasdomlan's answer but no one peer-reviewed & accepted it. so I post my own answer here:

```
$msg = array(
            'body'  => $body,
            'title' => $title,
            'android_channel_id' => $id
       );

$fields = array(
                'to' => $token,
                'notification'  => $msg
          );
```

where $id your channel_id string. You can read about it on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support , "Table 2b. Android — keys for notification messages"

Answer (score 2):

```
 $msg = array(
            'body'  => $body,
            'title' => $title,
            'channel_id' => $id,
            );

$fields = array(
                'to' => $token,
                'notification'  => $msg
                );
```

where `$id` your channel_id string